# Will I get sick from being bitten by a street kitten?

Tags: cats, health

I rescued a sick kitten from the street and brought it home. 
She's sweet but she's sick and don't have much appetite. It accidentally bit me while I was trying to feed her...Its a tiny wound, like a needle prick but it bled.. I wash it with soap and disinfect with alcohol..  Will I get sick? :(

Comment: You probably arn't gonna catch a thing, but just in case, get you and your kitty checked.

Answer (score 3):

I'd actually suggest both of you see your respective medical professionals - street kittens may not have necessary vaccinations and there's always the risk of infection for both of you. The fact that she's sick is a good reason you should take precautions for both your sakes.

Not assuming the worst, say rabies, there's a reasonable chance of infection - cat scratch fever came to mind, but apparently something called pasturella's pretty common too. [Zoonotic diseases are a thing](http://www.vet.cornell.edu/fhc/Health_Information/brochure_zoonoticdisease.cfm).

So, get both you, and your new little friend checked out.